# Is cancelling the sending process of a packet in the linux kernel possible?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I would like to ask about the feasibility of aborting the sending process of a packet in the linux kernel. I have the following scenario: in a delay-critical application, we have packets of low and high priority. If a packet of high priority (identified by the first byte of the payload) arrives in sk_buf, it should be sent out as quickly as possible. This requires two things:

1. Clearing the device queue of low priority packets, which should be possible using the [qdisc->dequeue](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.20/include/net/sch_generic.h#L26) method.
2. Aborting the current sending process of a low priority packet. Is this possible?

I have checked the [kernel flow](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/kernel_flow) of the transmission path, and under ‘2.4 Link layer’ (sorry, direct linking does not work on the page), the documentation tells me that after some processing of the packet, hard_start_xmit() is called for the network device. This ‘will generate one or more commands to the network device for scheduling transfer of the buffer. After a while, the network device replies that it's done.’

This timespan is exactly when I would like to be able to tell the network device to cancel the ongoing sending process. Do you see any possibility to realise this?